# MySQL database returning inconsistent results for queries involving `in (...)` clauses with long lists

Tags: mysql, jdbc

My Java program used JDBC to run the query

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    foo
WHERE
    versionEnd = 0
    AND barId IN (
        '01HRCX6QP5CQY5T4EN6N7KZP0P',
        '01HRCX6QPKCKB2HBKAVPTFSR2C',
        '01HRCX6QPVYKQ01YF1B6AE1DAY',
        '01HRCX6QQ8TJC9C9EYF58FVRVW',
        '01HRCX6QQMRPAJ0D054RBGV0B3',
        '01HRCX6QV8YYKPXQ1DTWYS727Y',
        '01HRCX6QVJT6Y1EFCZX4797RHW',
        '01HRCX6QVXPXBEBE0TV3YDSGN6',
        '01HRCX6QW7J6VYTMVKKQSZGW10',
        '01HRCX6QWFD8MNN05M1Z8ZXVKD',
        '01HRCX6QWVRCH99KCJV8YX32W5',
        '01HRCX6QX6VMHYZX4TKWVB34FR',
        '01HRCX6QXE3692G14Z38XHHCV8',
        '01HRCX6QXTRHEF2RZZ2P2709EG',
        '01HRCX6QY55H5JTDFP50XZWG0Q',
        '01HRCX6QYZFADFTV1MR59P6ZMD',
        '01HRCX6QZAMR321G3NB7KVK91G',
        '01HRCX6QZJGFMG6W4C7MRDVY0F',
        '01HRD9Z10VX8YHHG9E0T5XJQXV'
    )
    AND status != 'CANCELED'
```

and it failed to return a result I was expecting.  When I ran the same query in Sequel Pro against the same database, the result was returned.  Anyone ever see inconsistent behavior when working with queries like this?

I confirmed that there is a `foo` in the `foo` table which satisfies the conditions of the query (`versionEnd = 0`, `barId` is `01HRD9Z10VX8YHHG9E0T5XJQXV`, and `status = 'POSTED'`).  I can select for it by its `id` and confirm this.

**I expect** that if there is a `foo` meeting the conditions of the query

```
SELECT * 
FROM foo 
WHERE versionEnd = 0 
  AND barId = '01HRD9Z10VX8YHHG9E0T5XJQXV' 
  AND status != 'CANCELED'
```

then it will also be returned among the results of the query in my question.

**Actual** behavior was that it was NOT returned when the above query was run in the context of a Java program using JDBC.

Comment: You almost certainly have some data related issue.  The result of the MySQL query should not vary whether you call it from Workbench/command line or from JDBC.

Comment: If the results differ in workbench and JDBC, you are not connecting to the same database.

Comment: Bracket the problem: you found a query that returns no rows; what query can you run via JDBC that returns any rows. e.g. Try `SELECT * FROM foo LIMIT 5`. Then keep changing the query to be closer to what you're trying to make work and see when it stops returning rows.